# Using "If" statements or commands in VBA

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I need help with the proper formatting and structure for using an IF statement in VBA to get it to write out certain numbers and values in a cell itself.

I have ZERO experience in coding, in any form, so my wording above might be nonsense-able. So i'll just explain a bit more what i need.

I need to assign letter grades based of percentages using a macro that will work one line at a time. So if the % is 73.5, I need to have the cell next to it read "C" when I use the keyboard shortcut I assign in the macro and have that work no matter what the % is. I know I need to use "If/Then/ElseIF" format, but I simply cannot figure out how to properly type out the command

Comment: This is not a tutorial site, and we're not a code writing service. You can search to find any number of VBA tutorials, and there are plenty of existing posts here related to VBA that will demonstrate the proper use of IF ELSE.

Comment: You don't need VBA for this.  Something like `=IF(D2>99,"A",IF(D2<60,"F",CHAR(75-(D2+1)/10)))` should be sufficient.

Comment: First search returned when I Google [if then else vba](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx). First search returned when I Google [if then else excel formula](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php) seems to be a tutorial. :/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -2):

You'll need a couple of things here

1. A loop to iterate over your cells that you will test
2. An if or case statement to make the decision

It will look something like:

```
 For Each testCell in Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20").Cells
     If testCell.value > .70 AND testCell.value < .80 Then
         testCell.Offset(,1).value = "C"
     ElseIf testCell.value > .60 AND testCell.value < .70 Then
         testCell.Offset(,1).value = "D"
     <and on and on to capture each of your potential grades>
     End IF
 Next testCell
```

That `testCell` is a variable that is assigned the value of each cell in the range `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20"). One cell at a time, 20 times total as it loops. Each time it is tested by the`IF`statement and a value is written out in the cell one column over using the`Offset(,1)`.

You might find it easier, though, to use Index() and Match to manage this so you don't have to monkey with vba. To do this, make a table in another sheet (Sheet2) something like:

[image]

And then, assuming your number grade is in `A1`, you can use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5,MATCH(A1, Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5,1))
```